# Не могу установить numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, библиотеки, pydroid

При попытке установить numpy на pydroid3 вылезает эта ошибка

`Checking for function "csin" with dependency -lm: NO`

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Вам написали в консоле, обновите пип. Вы это сделали? pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: @Amgarak, к ошибке текст с предложением обновить pip не имеет ни какого отношения.

Comment: @wchistow Я когда ставил numpy на pydroid3, он у меня тоже ругался на устаревший pip, обновил его и всё нормально установилось. А так конечно не эксперт этого зверя, и вполне возможно проблема не в этом, но тогда в чем?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пакеты в pydroid нужно устанавливать через их собственный репозиторий. В меню выберите `Pip`, в строке поиска наберите `numpy` и вуаля

[image: numpy on pydroid3]

Пример

```
import numpy as np
print(np.sin(np.linspace(0,10,50)))
```

Результат

[image: result]

Comment: Абсолютно та же самая ошибка

Comment: @КИТKIT переустановите pydroid3. Или как минимум очистите кэш: `pip cache purge`